# PHP can't update SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a php part in my site, where I have a textarea that get a text from a database. The user can edit this text and after he finish press the save button, and using UPDATE I will change the text in the database.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userdb","codedb","projectdb");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');  
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $myQueryfac="SELECT text FROM main WHERE id=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$myQueryfac);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $t1=$row['text'];
    }

    $form="<form action='adminindex.php' method='post'>
        <textarea name='area1' maxlength='1500' cols='50' rows='10'>$t1</textarea>
        <input type='submit' name='enter' value='Save'>
        </form>";


    if($_POST['enter']) {
        $t1=$_POST['area1'];
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE main SET text='$t1' WHERE id='1'");
    }

    echo $form;
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My problem is in the UPDATE query it seems like it ignores $t1 and nothing change in database. But if I put something random in there, "RANDOM TEXT", change it successful.

Comment: 1. You don't check for errors which would be helpful here. 2. You are wide open to SQL injections

Comment: btw `$t1=$row['text'];` will allways override the result... in your case, your select has only one result... you don't need `while`.. just `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: Its just a project in our school. I'm new on this.

Comment: ohh thanks for this. I didn't know it.

Comment: Have you checked you're getting an output for `$_POST['area1']` ?

Comment: Yes I checked it with an echo, and every change made in there is successful.

Comment: selecting from db works ?

Comment: Yes, and I dont see the reason why is this happeing. If I put instead of $t1 "Hello there", it updates it succesfully, but also if I place an echo $t1 before update query, I get the new change text but nothing change in db

Comment: you should use mysqli in a OOP way anyway :) `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "foo");` and than `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bar")`

Comment: hmm I see, I'm new with all this and I surely make some unneeded things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

**test.php**

```
// DB Connect
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userdb","codedb","projectdb");
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Handle POST
if (count($_POST))
{
    // Save In DB
    mysqli_query($con, sprintf("UPDATE main SET `text`='%s' WHERE id=%d",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['area1']),
        1)); // id

    // Success
    echo "<p>Data updated.</p>";
}

// Load Existing Data
$myQueryfac="SELECT `text` FROM main WHERE id=1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $myQueryfac);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// Display Form
echo "<form action='test.php' method='post'>
    <textarea name='area1' maxlength='1500' cols='50' rows='10'>". $row['text'] ."</textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='enter' value='Save'>
    </form>";

// DB Close
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

---

### What I've changed

- Moved the post hander up (above the select statement), so that if an update occurs, the form will show the latest updated data
- Your update query was treating the `id` as string, I formatted it to be a digit (`%d`)
- Removed the while loop, you don't need it as it is a single row being returned
- added sql-injection prevention (using `sprintf` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`)
- added backticks `` around the db field name `text` (wasn't sure if this is a reserved word, because it's one of the sql data types)

Comment: Ohh man thank you sooooo much. Everything works perfect with this. I still can't track my mistake, and it took me a while to understand how "Update in DB" works that's why I'm late. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE main SET text='$t1' WHERE id=1");
```

Instead

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE main SET text='$t1' WHERE id='1'");
```

It could be the WHERE condition that bring your problems

Comment: no its not, had the same post and he tried already :D just deleted my post

Comment: Woups, did't see this. My bad then :)

Comment: you couldn't... i just deleted my post ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the `$_POST` array for a value not existing. `enter` is your submit button and will not send a value.

Try this:

```
if($_POST['area1']) {
    $t1=$_POST['area1'];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE main SET text='$t1' WHERE id='1'");
}
```